# Cannot install python-poppler-qt5 on windows 8.1

Tags: python, qt, poppler

I got this error when trying to install python-poppler-qt5 on windows 8.1 **"Failed to determine Qt version ([WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified)"**

I have googled the whole day but still couldn't find the solution to that. What's the problem?

Comment: see this: https://github.com/wbsoft/python-poppler-qt5/blob/master/INSTALL#L51

Comment: I still got the same error when running python setup.py build:  "Failed to determine Qt version ([WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified)".  Any idea, pleas?

Comment: Have you installed the dependencies?

Comment: Could you tell me what they are? I have installed sip and PyQt5 but don't know what else I need.

Comment: Download Qt5; https://www.qt.io/download , https://www1.qt.io/offline-installers/ and poppler-qt5: https://sourceforge.net/projects/poppler-qt5-mingw32/

Comment: 2.3 GB, that's big. But I will try. Thanks for your help eyllanesc. I'll see if it can solve the problem.

Comment: Have you succeed to install it? I installed Qt5, PyQt5 5.11.3, PyQt5-sip 4.19.13 and still no luck with `python-poppler-qt5`?  I get `Failed to determine Qt version ([WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified).` error.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in cmd:

```
pip install python-qt5
```

Your problem should be solved now.