# Cannot install python-poppler-qt5 on windows 7 in python virtual environment

Tags: windows, python-3.x, virtualenv, poppler

Essentially, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311856/cannot-install-python-poppler-qt5-on-windows-8-1), except I am trying to install python-doppler-qt5 inside a python virtual environment. I have SIP and PyQt5 pip installed inside my virtual environment, but Visual Studio tools and Qt are globally installed on Windows, and I seem to be getting an error indicating the virtual environment doesn't seem to know where to look to find the Qt version.

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\my_path_here> pip install python-poppler-qt5
Collecting python-poppler-qt5
  Downloading python-poppler-qt5-0.24.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\python_poppler_qt5.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\python_poppler_qt5.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\python_poppler_qt5.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\python_poppler_qt5.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\python_poppler_qt5.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    Failed to determine Qt version ([WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified).
```

I imagine this is some kind of path issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.